# Digital Signature BlueJ Error

Tags: java, javascript, bluej

I made a program for the question:

> Write a program in Java to input first name, middle name and last name. Validate the digital signature that contains first name and last name. If the signature doesn't contain any of these, print "Invalid Signature". Also, print his full name in a single line.

The program that I wrote for this is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.*;
public class TaskPE_4
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader read=
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter your first name");
        String fn=read.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your middle name");
        String mn=read.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your last name");
        String ln=read.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your digital signature");
        String ds=read.readLine();
        ds+=" ";
        if(fnCheck(fn, ds)&&lnCheck(ln, ds))
            System.out.println("Valid Digital Signature");
        else
            System.out.println("Invalid Digital Signature");
        System.out.println("Your full name is "+fn+" "+mn+" "+ln+".");
    }

    private static boolean fnCheck(String fn, String ds)
    {
        int fnl=fn.length();
        int dsl=ds.length();
        for(int i=0; i<=(dsl-fnl); i++)
            if((ds.substring(i, (i+fnl))).equals(fnl))
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean lnCheck(String ln, String ds)
    {
        int lnl=ln.length();
        int dsl=ds.length();
        for(int i=0; i<=(dsl-lnl); i++)
            if((ds.substring(i, (i+lnl))).equals(lnl))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The output shown is:

```
Enter your first name
Rachit
Enter your middle name
Rachit
Enter your last name
Bhargava
Enter your digital signature
Rachit Bhargava
Invalid Digital Signature
Your full name is Rachit Rachit Bhargava.
```

Please help me debug this program.

Comment: what you mean by saying help me to debug this program? do you get any error?

Comment: yes! the place where it is showing Invalid Digital Signature. it showed be Valid Digital Signature.

Comment: can you explain how fnCheck and inCheck private functions? what you try to achieve by them?

Comment: i don't want fnCheck and lnCheck functions to be accessed from outside the program. so, i have made them private!

Comment: no I know that but what they try to do? if your ds is consist of fn and ls, I think it is easier way to check it? did i get the point of ds right?

Comment: sorry, but, i did not get you. what are you trying to say?

Comment: no, if i do not provide the functions with the digital signature, how are they going to check whether first name and last name are there in the digital signature or not?

Comment: there is no need you can check it with contains functions. outsiders do not know how you check your ds. do they?

Comment: you just try to make your life complicated

Comment: this is an assignment given to me by my teacher. he is going to check it and will surely ask me this question. please answer my question how will the functions get the digital signature and i'll select your answer.

Comment: your teacher gave you those functions?

Comment: what happened that you changed your mind?

Comment: i didn't look that you added .contains. i thought that you were providing the functions with only fn or ln. thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: happy to help. good luck and avoid making your life complicated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you should do this if I get your question right**

Instead of using those functions to check your digital signature, you should use `contains()` function to check if the digital signature consists of first name and last name.

Code:

```
if (ds.contains(fn)&& ds.contains(ln)) {
            System.out.println("Valid Digital Signature");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Digital Signature");
        }
```

Output:

```
Enter your first name
Rachit
Enter your middle name
Rachit
Enter your last name
Bhargava
Enter your digital signature
Rachit Bhargava
Valid Digital Signature
Your full name is Rachit Rachit Bhargava.
```

Sources:

[String.contains in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046809/string-contains-in-java)